# How to implement a concept of WCF service that encapsulates other WCF services?

Tags: c#, wcf

I'll try to explain what I want in code, cause can't formulate it in words.

I have some kind of resource and I encapsulate its usage in a WCF service, and I have a resource manager that controls access to this resources which is also a WCF service, something like this:

```
//Allows only one client to use it at the same time...
public interface IResource
{
    string GetResourceDescription();
    void DoWork();
    void BeginWork();
    void EndWork();
}

//Governs access and location of resources
public interface IResourceManager
{
    IEnumerable<string> GetResourcesDescriptions();
    bool IsResourceAvailable(string resourceDescription);
    void BeginWorkWith(string resourceDescription);
    void DoWorkWith(string resourceDescription)
    void EndWorkWith(string resourceDescription);
}
```

What I don't like in this code is that when working with `IResourceManager` I need to always tell what resource I want to use for service operation, so basically `IResourceManager` have the same service operations as `IResource` but takes additional `IResource` identifier as parameter.

What I want is:

```
public interface IResourceManager
{
    IEnumerable<string> GetResourcesDescriptions();
    //I want it to return service proxy (ICommunicationObject)
    IResource GetResource(string resourceDescription);
}
```

First this is impossible, second, the clients can't communicate with `IResource` directly on network layer (there is no direct connection).

So far I found only one not ugly solution, to create a client side wrapper, that mimics this behavior. How to implement, and use such WCF services?

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that objects returned from service operations are only data. On the other side of communication channel, these objects will be "dead" (will contain only data, no methods). The only way to deal with it, is the way you solve it. Client side wrapper sounds nice and I think it is reasonable solution.